# I want to push more arrays into this Hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, graph, hash, push

i want to push an array into this part, i'm a newbie in Ruby

```
@edge_weights = {[position, position2] => node_distance}
```

That is a Hash? i think i want to push some other hashes of the same way to have a result like this:

```
{["1", "2"]=>2445, ["2", "3"]=>2015, ["2", "4"]=>1547, ["3", "4"]=>939, ["5", "1"]=>1548}
```

Not like this:

```
{["1", "2"]=>111},{["2", "3"]=>222},{["1", "3"]=>333}
```

How can i achieve this?. Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: I think you should do some reading on Ruby `array` and `hash`

Comment: You're free to say `some_hash[['1','2']] = 2445`, an array is a hash key like any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you will begin with some data such as the following array of arrays:

```
arr = [["1", "2", 2445], ["2", "3", 2015], ["2", "4", 1547],
       ["3", "4", 939], ["5", "1", "7", 1548], ["1", "2", -71]]
```

Step one is to create an empty hash:

```
h = {}
```

Now iterate over the elements of `arr` to build the hash `h`.

```
arr.each do |a|
  *first, last = a
  h[first] = last
end
  #=> [["1", "2", 2445], ["2", "3", 2015], ["2", "4", 1547],
  #    ["3", "4", 939], ["5", "1", "7", 1548], ["1", "2", -71]]
```

We want the value of `h`, not the above return value.

```
h #=> {["1", "2"]=>-71, ["2", "3"]=>2015, ["2", "4"]=>1547,
  #    ["3", "4"]=>939, ["5", "1"]=>1548, ["5", "1", "7"]=>1548}
```

Note that Ruby's *splat* operator<sup>1</sup> is used to break up an array in various ways:

```
*first, last = ["5", "1", "7", 1548]
first
  #=> ["5", "1", "7"]
last
  #=> 1548
```

Is the result above for `h` what you were expecting? Recall that hashes have unique keys. After the first element of `arr` is passed to the block we execute

```
h[["1", "2"]] = 2445
```

so that `h` becomes `{ ["1", "2"]=>2445 }`. Later, when the last element of `arr`--which has the same key (`["1", "2"]`)--is passed to the block, we execute

```
h[["1", "2"]] = -71
```

which *overwrites* the value of that key. If you'd prefer to keep the value of the *first* key encountered you could write

```
arr.each do |a|
  *first, last = a
  h[first] = last unless h.key?(first)
end
```

See [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) (aka, `has_key?` and `include?`). (Aside: you could write `...if !h.key?(first)`, `!` read *not*, but it's generally clearer to avoid negation by using `unless`.)

The "Ruby way" of writing the original construct is to use the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and to splat the block variables `a`:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(*first, last),h|
  h[first] = last
end
  #=> {["1", "2"]=>-71, ["2", "3"]=>2015, ["2", "4"]=>1547,
  #    ["3", "4"]=>939, ["5", "1"]=>1548, ["5", "1", "7"]=>1548}
```

This avoids the need to use a separate statement to create an empty hash and the code block returns the value of `h`.

(Don't worry if you don't understand this.)

One other common way to construct a hash is to use the method [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`):

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(*first, last),h|
  h.update({ first=>last })
end
```

Note Ruby allows a shorthand version of the second line:

```
  h.update(first=>last)
```

<sup>1 See "Multiple variable assignment" [here](https://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html).</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, i ended by using the last lines, also a very complete answer, thanks a lot mate. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Glad to help. Every time I see someone apologizing for their English I am reminded of my woeful knowledge of languages other than English.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass array as `key` and assign `value` to it:

```
> edge_weights = {}
> edge_weights[["1","2"]] = 2445
> edge_weights[["2", "4"]] = 1547
> edge_weights
#=> {["1", "2"]=>2445, ["2", "4"]=>1547}
```